# CASE statement in the ORDER BY CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL SERVER

I'm attempting to sort records in my ORDER BY clause in an exact manner. So the records should be sorted in the following manner. I think my issue might be the CASE STATEMENT syntax, but I can't seem to find anything telling me that it's wrong, other than the code not running.

od.Status
Firm,
In Process,
Released,
Everything Else

I believed I could assign each type of record a number, and then sort those numbers.

The code below gives me "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified"

```
SELECT DISTINCT
oh.Order_Number AS Order_Number,
oh.Status AS Order_Status,
oh.Customer_Name AS Customer_Name,
vsc.Salesman_Name AS Salesman_Name,
vsc.Email_Address AS Email_Address,
od.Work_Code AS Work_Code,
od.Product_Code AS Product_Code,
CONVERT(char(10),od.Projected_Ship_Date,101) AS Projected_Ship_Date,
CONVERT(char(10),od.Due_Date,101) AS OD_Due_Date,
format(oh.Gross_Amount, '$#,##0.##') AS Gross_Amount,
DATEDIFF(DAY,oh.Order_Date,'{%Current Date%}') AS DIP,
od.Part_Number AS Part_Number,
od.Status AS Status,
CAST(qd.Delivery_Notes AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Delivery_Notes


FROM

dbo.Order_Header oh LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Commission_Distribution cd ON oh.Order_Header_ID = cd.Order_Header_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.vSalesman_Code vsc ON cd.Salesman_Code = vsc.Salesman_Code JOIN
dbo.Order_Detail od ON od.Order_Header_ID = oh.Order_Header_ID JOIN
dbo.Quotation_Detail qd ON od.Quotation_Detail_ID = qd.Quotation_Detail_ID JOIN
dbo.Quotation_Header qh ON qd.Quotation_Header_ID = qh.Quotation_Header_ID

WHERE

oh.Status  =  'Open' AND
cd.Company_Code  =  'AIN' AND
oh.Customer_Name  NOT IN  ( 'A.I. Innovations' , 'AI PROPERTIES Fortville LLC' , 'AI-IN Intercompany' , 'AI-NC Intercompany' ) AND
od.Status  <>  'Closed' AND
LEFT(od.Part_Number, 3)  <>  'MTS' AND
vsc.Salesman_Name  NOT IN  ( 'House' , 'House Accounts' ) AND
od.Status  <>  'Hold' AND
od.Product_Code NOT LIKE '%PROCES%' AND
od.Product_Code NOT LIKE '%VISTA WARRANT%'


ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN od.Status = 'Firm' THEN 1
WHEN od.Status = 'In Process' THEN 2
WHEN od.Status = 'Released' THEN 3
ELSE 4
END,
vsc.Email_Address ASC, 
CONVERT(char(10),od.Projected_Ship_Date,101) ASC
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. I haven't been able to find very much on this issue. Most issues I've found want to sort one set DESC, and another set ASC, but not in a particular order.

Thanks

Comment: You just need to put your case statement in your select, that is what the error is saying. @allmhuran gave a nice example.

Comment: `CASE` *expression*, not statement.

Comment: Thank you for correcting.

Comment: Why do you have `DISTINCT` anyway, that is usually an indication of poor join logic. Also, to truncate a `datetime` to a `date` simply `CAST(Projected_Ship_Date AS date)`. Also, `LEFT JOIN` followed by `WHERE` on that table results in an `INNER JOIN`, you need to move the filter into the `ON` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   oh.Order_Number AS Order_Number,
   oh.Status AS Order_Status,   
   oh.Customer_Name AS Customer_Name,
   vsc.Salesman_Name AS Salesman_Name,
   vsc.Email_Address AS Email_Address,
   od.Work_Code AS Work_Code,
   od.Product_Code AS Product_Code,
   CONVERT(char(10),od.Projected_Ship_Date,101) AS Projected_Ship_Date,
   CONVERT(char(10),od.Due_Date,101) AS OD_Due_Date,
   format(oh.Gross_Amount, '$#,##0.##') AS Gross_Amount,
   DATEDIFF(DAY,oh.Order_Date,'{%Current Date%}') AS DIP,
   od.Part_Number AS Part_Number,   
   od.Status AS Status,
   CAST(qd.Delivery_Notes AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Delivery_Notes,
   CASE 
       WHEN od.Status = 'Firm' THEN 1      
       WHEN od.Status = 'In Process' THEN 2
       WHEN od.Status = 'Released' THEN 3
       ELSE 4
    END As StatusOrderId

FROM
    dbo.Order_Header oh LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Commission_Distribution cd ON 
    oh.Order_Header_ID = cd.Order_Header_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.vSalesman_Code vsc ON cd.Salesman_Code = vsc.Salesman_Code JOIN
    dbo.Order_Detail od ON od.Order_Header_ID = oh.Order_Header_ID JOIN
    dbo.Quotation_Detail qd ON od.Quotation_Detail_ID = qd.Quotation_Detail_ID JOIN
    dbo.Quotation_Header qh ON qd.Quotation_Header_ID = qh.Quotation_Header_ID

WHERE

    oh.Status  =  'Open' AND
    cd.Company_Code  =  'AIN' AND
    oh.Customer_Name  NOT IN  ( 'A.I. Innovations' , 'AI PROPERTIES Fortville LLC' , 'AI-IN Intercompany' , 'AI-NC Intercompany' ) AND
    od.Status  <>  'Closed' AND
    LEFT(od.Part_Number, 3)  <>  'MTS' AND
    vsc.Salesman_Name  NOT IN  ( 'House' , 'House Accounts' ) AND
    od.Status  <>  'Hold' AND
    od.Product_Code NOT LIKE '%PROCES%' AND
    od.Product_Code NOT LIKE '%VISTA WARRANT%'

ORDER BY
   CASE 
       WHEN od.Status = 'Firm' THEN 1
       WHEN od.Status = 'In Process' THEN 2
       WHEN od.Status = 'Released' THEN 3
       ELSE 4
   END,
   vsc.Email_Address ASC, 
   CONVERT(char(10),od.Projected_Ship_Date,101) ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, that makes perfect sense now. I guess I didn't read the error as closely as I should have. If it's in the Order By, it has to be in the Select. Now that makes sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "case" statement in your `order by` must actually appear as a column in the select statement because you are doing a `select distinct`. Here is an example, the first query is invalid, the second works

```sql
select    distinct 
          tableName = t.name
from      sys.tables t
order by  case 
            when t.name like '%something%' then 1
            else 2
          end;


select    distinct 
          orderingColumn = case 
                              when t.name like '%something%' then 1
                              else 2
                           end,
          tableName      = t.name
from      sys.tables t
order by  case 
            when t.name like '%something%' then 1
            else 2
          end
```

The problem here is that the orderingColumn will be returned by the select statement, and it seems like you don't want that, but that's easily fixed by a CTE or subquery:

```sql
with MyQuery as 
(
   select    distinct 
             orderingColumn = case 
                                 when t.name like '%something%' then 1
                                 else 2
                              end,
             tableName      = t.name
   from      sys.tables t
)
select tableName from MyQuery order by orderingColumn;
```